# GAE Python 3.7 Standard can't connect to Cloud SQL server

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm following the tutorial for deploying a Django app on Google App Engine [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine). I'm able to run the app locally using `cloud_sql_proxy`, but when I deploy the app to GAE the app fails with the error:

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

Checking the error output, it looks like django is trying to connect to the unix socket at `/cloudsql/<project>:<region>:<instance>` as expected, it's just failing for some reason. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: I've not completed the tutorial but I'm familiar with App Engine and Cloud SQL. The error you include (`"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'`) conflicts with your statement that it looks like it's using the `/cloudsql/<project>:<region>:<instance>` socket. The error suggest it's not. Looking at the tutorial, it determines whether it's local or deployed using `os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None)`. Did you change this? if not, perhaps either try logging the value of the environment variable to confirm which path it's taking or brute force it to always use the `/cloudsql/...` path.

Comment: Yeah I thought that seemed contradictory too, but django outputs a list of connection variables and I see `/cloudsql/<project>:<region>:<instance>` in there. Executing that branch is the only way it would get defined. Just to make sure I set the statement to `if True` and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: It looks like the following condition isn't being met so it's trying to establish a local TCP connection: `if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):`. Try reviewing the [entire code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python37/django/mysite/settings.py) to make sure you aren't omitting something

Comment: If you don't get this resolved by my tomorrow morning, I'll try the tutorial.

Comment: It works for me. I encourage you to double-check that you've followed the instructions.

Comment: It looks like it was an issue with my project settings. I was able to get the tutorial working in a new project. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was with the project I was using for the tutorial. Somehow the Google App Engine service account for that project had gotten its permissions revoked. After restoring those permissions (giving it the Editor role) the tutorial worked on the original project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the database connnection in the Django settings.

`appengine/standard_python37/django/mysite/settings.py`

The settings.py file contains the configuration for your SQL database. The code in settings.py uses the GAE_APPLICATION environment variable to determine whether the app is running on App Engine or running on your local computer:

When the app runs on App Engine, it connects to the MySQL host by using the /cloudsql Unix socket.
When the app runs on your local computer, it connects to the MySQL host by using TCP, which requires a username and password.

Read the bottom of the documentation, [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine)

Edit: make sure you've enabled the Cloud SQL API.